# Problem with multiple request in subscribe

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am invoking a method on my component that loads the address information through the postalcode entered in the input.
First I am invoking the method that loads the information into the getAddress$ variable, then subscribe to it to get the data and assign it to form inputs.
On the first page load, it only executes one call in the api, but as I inform another postalcode, my subscribe will add one more return, making more than one call to the api.
What I want to do is for each postalcode entered, give me only 1 result for each postal code.
Below is my code, the method is firing on the input blur event.
I have already implemented all the unsuccessful solutions contained in this article https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0
Could you help me with this problem please? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
// class CommonEffect

@Injectable()
export class CommonEffect {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions,
        private authApi: CommonService) {
    }
    @Effect()
    getAddress$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(actions.ActionTypes.GET_ADDRESS),
            map((action: actions.GetAddress) => action.payload),
            switchMap((state) => {
                return this.authApi.getAddress(state)
                    .pipe(
                        map((address) => new actions.GetAddressSuccess(address)),
                        catchError(error => of(new actions.GetAddressFail(error)))
                    );
            })
        );
}



// function reducer

export function reducer(state = initialState, { type, payload }: any): CommonState {

    if (!type) {

        return state;
    }
    switch (type) {
        case actions.ActionTypes.GET_ADDRESS:
            {

                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    getAddressLoading: true,
                    getAddressLoaded: false,
                    getAddressFailed: false,
                });
            }

        case actions.ActionTypes.GET_ADDRESS_SUCCESS: {
            const tempAddress = new SearchAddressModel(payload.data);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                address: tempAddress,
                getAddressLoading: false,
                getAddressLoaded: true,
                getAddressFailed: false,
            });
        }
        case actions.ActionTypes.GET_ADDRESS_FAIL:
            {
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    getAddressLoading: false,
                    getAddressLoaded: true,
                    getAddressFailed: true,
                });
            }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

// class CommonSandbox

@Injectable()
export class CommonSandbox {

    /* get address*/
    public getAddress$ = this.appState$.select(getAddress);
    public addressLoading$ = this.appState$.select(addressLoading);
    public addressLoaded$ = this.appState$.select(addressLoaded);
    public addressFailed$ = this.appState$.select(addressFailed);

    constructor(private router: Router,
        protected appState$: Store<store.AppState>,
    ) {
    }
    public getAddress(params) : void {
        this.appState$.dispatch(new commonAction.GetAddress(params));
    }

}

// class component

export class AddaddressesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    addAddressForm: FormGroup;
    addressId: any;
    openAddress = false;
    private subscriptions: Array<Subscription> = [];

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public snackBar: MatSnackBar, public commonSandbox: CommonSandbox, public accountSandbox: AccountSandbox) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.addressId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.addAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'firstName': ['', Validators.required],
            'lastName': ['', Validators.required],
            'address': ['', Validators.required],
            'phoneNumber': '',
            'phoneMobileNumber': ['', Validators.required],
            'complement': '',
            'reference': '',
            'addresstype': '',
            'city': ['', Validators.required],
            'zone': ['', Validators.required],
            'state': ['', Validators.required],
            'postalcode': ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.addAddressForm.patchValue({ addresstype: '1', tc: true });

    }

    // method (blur) search address for postalcode
    public getSeacrhAddress(value: any) {
        if (value) {

            // Here I call the api that returns the address according to the postalcode entered, below I retrieve the value through subscribe.
            this.commonSandbox.getAddress(value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''));

            // the subscribe address parameter in the first pass on the first page load is undefined, as I inform another postalcode it always has the previous value
            this.subscriptions.push(this.commonSandbox.getAddress$.subscribe(address => {
               //With the breakpoint here, each postalcode you enter will increment one more pass instead of just once.
                if (address) {
                    this.addAddressForm.controls['address'].setValue(address.logradouro);
                    this.addAddressForm.controls['city'].setValue(address.localidade);
                    this.addAddressForm.controls['zone'].setValue(address.bairro);
                    this.addAddressForm.controls['state'].setValue(address.uf);
                    this.openAddress = true;
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    // destroy the subscribed events while page destroy
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(each => {
            each.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend making a dumb form component that knows nothing about the router or the store and passing the data via the async pipe and patching to your form via ngOnChanges. You can use selectors to combine data in any way you need rather than ugly multiple subscribe logic that can ensue otherwise. See this [talk](https://2018.ng-conf.org/sessions/ngrx-complex-form/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add to `this.subscriptions` on every `blur` event. Instead you can subscribe to it once in `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addressId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.addAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': ['', Validators.required],
      'lastName': ['', Validators.required],
      'address': ['', Validators.required],
      'phoneNumber': '',
      'phoneMobileNumber': ['', Validators.required],
      'complement': '',
      'reference': '',
      'addresstype': '',
      'city': ['', Validators.required],
      'zone': ['', Validators.required],
      'state': ['', Validators.required],
      'postalcode': ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.addAddressForm.patchValue({ addresstype: '1', tc: true });

// the subscribe address parameter in the first pass on the first page load is undefined, as I inform another postalcode it always has the previous value
    this.subscriptions.push(this.commonSandbox.getAddress$.subscribe(address => {
      //With the breakpoint here, each postalcode you enter will increment one more pass instead of just once.
      if (address) {
        this.addAddressForm.controls['address'].setValue(address.logradouro);
        this.addAddressForm.controls['city'].setValue(address.localidade);
        this.addAddressForm.controls['zone'].setValue(address.bairro);
        this.addAddressForm.controls['state'].setValue(address.uf);
        this.openAddress = true;
      }
    }));

  }

  // method (blur) search address for postalcode
  public getSeacrhAddress(value: any) {
    if (value) {

      // Here I call the api that returns the address according to the postalcode entered, below I retrieve the value through subscribe.
      this.commonSandbox.getAddress(value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''));
    }
  }
```

Comment: 512/5000
Pankaj had already implemented this way and it is working, you have confirmed that the implementation is really correct. Now I understand the operation, it is necessary to read the first state of the component in ngOnInt for the reducer to return a new state with the included API return modifications.
As I am using ngrx for the first time, I am thinking of imperative programming and in this ngrx framework I have to think of reactive programming.
I will mark your answer as a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

`take(1)` should work but it is important where you put it.
I didn't test the following code but I think this will work for you:

```
@Effect()
getAddress$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(actions.ActionTypes.GET_ADDRESS),
    take(1),
    map((action: actions.GetAddress) => action.payload),
    switchMap((state) => {
      return this.authApi.getAddress(state)
        .pipe(
          take(1)
          map((address) => new actions.GetAddressSuccess(address)),
          catchError(error => of(new actions.GetAddressFail(error)))
        );
    })
  );
```

Note that `take(1)` is called only after the filter on the first getAddress call.

Are you sure that the first map will get action? I think the first map might get address.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for the answer. With take(1) only one request happens, if I enter another postalcode in the input in the blur event does not trigger a new request. The problem that occurs without take(1) is that with each request the return accumulates within the this.commonSandbox.getAddress$ variable in subscribe, and should it be cleared every agree?